# Mouse moves independent from my commands

Tags: 16.04

Currently, I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my Lenovo z500 laptop. The wireless mouse (m215)- keyboard(k330) set is from logitech.

My problem is, each time when i turn on the laptop, after circa 20 minutes, the mouse pointer starts moving and clicking randomly. I can still control the mouse but it is like two people try to control the mouse at the same time.

It does not help when I remove the transceiver of the mouse. It continues.

This random movements last circa 2 minutes and does not happen in this session again.

What are your suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried with any other computer/OS ? Couldn't it be a hardware issue?

Comment: @M.Becerra Actually, before I installed Ubuntu, windows 10 was installed on my laptop and the same happened then

Comment: If that's the case then it's likely a hardware/firmware issue and unrelated to Ubuntu. I'd vote to close as off topic but I can't as long as there's an open bounty.

Comment: @DavidFoerster You are right. I may better update/change the current driver of the mouse and see what will happen.